# Allow backbonejs app to work offline

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4, offlineapps

I have a laravel 4 and backbonejs app that i am developing at the moment. The vast majority of the app is done, however a requirement is for it to work offline. Unfortunately for me I have never done this before and i am a bit stuck on where to start.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: If you are linking every js and css from offline, It will work in offline server.

Comment: you may have some trouble if you're using require.js. as @devo said if you can serve your resources while you're offline it should work.

Comment: I only want the backbone part of the app to work offline, how do do i get all the 'public' files to work offline?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Where you host the app? is it in your localhost?

Comment: Yes it in my localhost. I have started to use html5 manifest